# Troubles using RegEx on PHP

Tags: java, php, regex

I have a sip.conf file that contains data like that :

```
#<COMPTE
[6007](template)
fullname = ggg
username = ggg
secret = nana
COMPTE>#

#<COMPTE
[6008](template)
fullname = dada
username = dada
secret = dada
COMPTE>#
```

I have created a method using java :

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?m)^#<COMPTE.*?COMPTE>#",Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(chaine);
 while (matcher.find()) {       
       comptes=matcher.group();                     
}
```

I want something like that in PHP I have tried many things but it doesn't seems to work, any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
$chaine = <<<EOT
#<COMPTE
[6007](template)
fullname = ggg
username = ggg
secret = nana
COMPTE>#

#<COMPTE
[6008](template)
fullname = dada
username = dada
secret = dada
COMPTE>#
EOT;

$pattern = "/COMPTE(.*?)COMPTE/sm"; // s = dotall, m = multiline
preg_match_all($pattern, $chaine, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I changed it to : $pattern = "/COMPTE(.*?)COMPTE/sm";

I accecpt your answer, if you can edit it as I mentioned so other people find out the right answer ;)

Comment: I made the change. Thank you!